# Noise in sound in ios 4.3.x and 5.0 after recording

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audio

I've got an app where I use Core Audio for sound recording. Sound is made from some parts and then must be saved to the device. It was working fine but in some new ios versions I have a noise, something like distortion, in output files. What is the possible reason? `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL` is used to create output file and `ExtAudioFileSetProperty` to set its properties.
Any help will be appreciated.

This code was created by another programmer who is currently unavailable, so I don't have any idea why such hack was implemented.

The way sound buffer is created for different versions of ios:

```
static BOOL shouldFixData = NO;
    static int checkOnce = 1;
    if (checkOnce) {
        checkOnce = 0;
        if (inNumberFrames * 8 == ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize) {
            shouldFixData = YES;
        }
    }

    if (shouldFixData) {
        AudioBufferList cutData = {0};
        cutData.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        cutData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels;
        cutData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize / 2;
        cutData.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(cutData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

        SInt32* oldData = (SInt32*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
        SInt32* newData = (SInt32*)cutData.mBuffers[0].mData;
        int count = cutData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize/4;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            newData[i] = oldData[i*2];
        }

        ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(userData->outputFile, inNumberFrames, &cutData);
        free(cutData.mBuffers[0].mData);
    } else {
        ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(userData->outputFile, inNumberFrames, ioData);
    }
}
```

Saving the record:

```
 CAStreamBasicDescription dstFormat;
        dstFormat.mSampleRate = mOutputFormat.mSampleRate;
        dstFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;            
        dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
        dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
        dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;

        //recordInfo.output file is ExtAudioFileRef

        err = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)recordFileURL, kAudioFileWAVEType, &dstFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &recordInfo.outputFile);
        if (err) { printf("ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL result %ld %08X %4.4s\n", err, (unsigned int)err, (char*)&err); return; }

        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        NSComparisonResult versionCompareRes = [currSysVer compare:@"4.3" options:NSNumericSearch];
        if (versionCompareRes == NSOrderedSame || versionCompareRes == NSOrderedDescending) {
//for new versions
            err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(recordInfo.outputFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(mOutputFormat), &mOutputFormat);
            if (err) { printf("ExtAudioFileSetProperty result %ld %08X %4.4s\n", err, (unsigned int)err, (char*)&err); return; }
        } else {
            //for old versions
            err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(recordInfo.outputFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(dstFormat), &dstFormat);
            if (err) { printf("ExtAudioFileSetProperty result %ld %08X %4.4s\n", err, (unsigned int)err, (char*)&err); return; }
        }
```

sample output file:
[output.mp3](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7BryrZG7ul_NGEyZGQyZTgtNzMxOC00ZWYxLWE0YTctNThkZGFjYjEwNjVh)

Comment: Post an example **sound** clip.  This might not have anything to do with code, and I want to hear it to find out.

Comment: Also added link to google docs with sample audio.

Comment: That sound file is nothing but extreme clipping.  I doubt this has anything to do with your code.  You'll hear this if you plugged some line-level output into a microphone input.

Comment: Nope. It's not from microphone, it's created by mixing some input files and it sounds just fine in ios < 4.3. I guess, it's something about sound buffer and number of channels in it.

Comment: Any time you mix files by summing, you will need to lower each by half their level, or you risk overflow.  Perhaps this used to be done automatically, and no longer is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops.. should have been feedback. Sorry..

The main difference in the code you posted is the format setup
sizeof(mOutputFormat), &mOutputFormat
where mOutputFormat not specified how its set.

compared to the dst format for older version which is set.

Setting "wrong" format usually gives bad sound  :-)

Comment: It was initialized, but I forget to post it.
`mOutputFormat.SetAUCanonical(2, false);      
    mOutputFormat.mSampleRate = kGraphSampleRate;`
I will look at this direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SPEEX to do denoising, include speex_preprocess.h first:

```
SpeexPreprocessState *_spt = speex_preprocess_state_init(NN, 16000);/NN is 320 for sampleRate 16000.
int i=1;
speex_preprocess_ctl(_spt, SPEEX_PREPROCESS_SET_DENOISE, &i);

-(BOOL)doConvert:(void *)data SampleLength:(SInt64)length
{
    AudioBufferList *dataBuffer = (AudioBufferList*)data;
    AudioSampleType *samples = (AudioSampleType*)dataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mData;

    SInt64 count = length / NN;
    //short sample_ground[count][NN];

    short **sample_group;
    sample_group = (short**)malloc(sizeof(short*)*count);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        sample_group[i] = (short*)malloc(sizeof(short)*NN);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < NN; j++) {
            short value = samples[i*NN+j];
            sample_group[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        speex_preprocess_run(_spt, sample_group[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < NN; j++) {
            samples[i*NN+j] = sample_group[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        free(sample_group[i]);
    free(sample_group);

    return YES;
}
```